# How do i count down to different multiple dates

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple  tags and i am trying to do a date countdown function to get "innerHTML"  values for each of the tag i.e

```
document.GetElementById("id").innerHTML = getcountdown("Dec 5, 2019 15:37:12");
document.GetElementById("id2").innerHTML = getcountdown("Mar 5, 2020 11:37:29");
document.GetElementById("id3").innerHTML = getcountdown("Nov 8, 2019 18:40:25");
```

The error i am receiving from each value is "undefined" . I don't actually know where there error is from. kindly guide me.

Thanks.

Below is what i came up with. I am very new to JavaScript.

````js
```
   <script>

function getcountdown(dateobj) {

var dateobj ;

var countDownDate = new Date(dateobj).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() { 

 // Get todays date and time
var now = new Date().getTime();

 // Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;

 // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  

var retval =  days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + " " + seconds + "s ";
return retval;
  
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
 
   return "EXPIRED"
  }
}, 1000);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getcountdown("Dec 5, 2019 15:37:25");
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = getcountdown("Feb 14, 2010 15:37:25");
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = getcountdown("Mar 9, 2020 15:37:25");
```
</script>
````

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Date Countdown
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->


  <!-- creating array of the div element -->
  <div id="demo">1</div>
  <div id="demo2">2<div>
  <div id="demo3">3</div>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But what's the question or problem you have? Is your code working? If isn't, what kind of error do you get or what issue do you have? Please edit your question, and explain in detail, because it is currently unclear exactly what are you asking...

Comment: What doesn't work? If you're looking for code review, you're better off [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `demos` isn't defined except for a line of invalid code that is commented out, and you get an element with id `demos` except that element doesn't exist

Comment: Not a single thing is perfect in the above code , multiple declaration of same variable. For loop syntax is not valid . demos are not defined . etc .

Comment: your first priority here is to clear up all the basic syntax errors etc before you worry about the functionality. As we can now see from the runnable snippet, it's littered with simple mistakes which are obscuring the end goal. please check documentation/tutorials/examples etc so you can see and understand the syntax to use.

Comment: Can you make sure your dateobj properly creates a Date? I would use an ISO standard date format like yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: Also, your 1st return will end processing of the function, the 2nd will never be run.